# Getting a PHP syntax error when posting my site link on a facebook wall

Tags: php, facebook, syntax, hyperlink, facebook-comments

I'm getting the following message when I try to post http://www.247limosales.com as a comment in facebook:

http://247limosales.com/
: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/content/e/c/o/ecommphppro/html/247limosales/listings.php on line 462

I checked my PHP code and it's fine, I also have no problems on the actual site
itself, it generates the HTML properly, I don't understand why facebook is giving
this error.  Even if I go to "view code" on the site, I see no error like the one above

Here is the code around line 462:

```
// See if we have a unique hit      
$hitquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listinghits WHERE hitip='" . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . "' AND adid='" . $adid . "' LIMIT 1");

  if (!$hitquery)

  { echo mysql_error(); }
  if (mysql_num_rows($hitquery)==0)
  {
    $hitquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO listinghits (hitid, date, hitip, adid) VALUES ('', CURDATE(), '" . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . "', '" . $adid . "')");
    if (!$hitquery)
    { echo mysql_error(); }
  }
```

The very last line is line 62

Thank you

Comment: You've lost `;`, but this code is fine. There is a chance you're looking to a wrong file

Comment: There are no syntax errors in this code. Can you copy and paste a bit more of your code and indicate precisely which line is 462?

Comment: Add that in your code, so you can easily see what the query is: echo "INSERT INTO listinghits (hitid, date, hitip, adid) VALUES ('', CURDATE(), '" . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . "', '" . $adid . "')"

Comment: Always use mysql(i)_real_escape_string() when inserting data in a query. also start using mysqli. mysql is being depricated

Answer (score 0):

It will be either a ' or " in your adid string (use mysql_real_escape_string($adid)
OR
What is happening is the periods in the $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] as being treated as a concatenate such that it becomes:

```
select * from table where htip='".128.10.50.125."'" and it is breaking the string as it is expecting a ' or ".
```

Try:

```
select * from table where htip='".{$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]}."'
```

Comment: You could also do select * from table where htip='"{$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]}"'